# iOS Cordova Plugin memory management: When does the dealloc method of a iOS cordova plugin gets called?

Tags: ios, cordova

I have created an iOS application using phonegap. To use the native iOS camera, I have written a plugin which extends CDVPlugin.

In the plugin class, I have dealloc method. But that is never getting called. I have to release some variables there and because of which I am getting critical memory leaks.

Please advice me how to manage memory in a cordova plugin class.

THANKS IN ADVANCE.....

Comment: I am working on a non-ARC project